# I need help fixing an illegal file path in desktop caused by one drive

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

The Desktop's name in One Drive contains Chinese characters and it has issues with programs (For example it breaks zip folders, a bunch of programs like Arduino, etc). The orginal desktop system folder is still there, but has nothing in it. How can I fix this? I tried redirecting the "false-desktop" folder to the orginal folder, but I got a warning when redirecting to a system folder that I cannot undo it. How can I fix this issue? Renaming is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you backing up your desktop folder to OneDrive?

If so, I suggest you stop syncing desktop folder to OneDrive.

To do this, it's recommended to backup all files and folders in desktop folder to your local computer first.

Then click on OneDrive icon on taskbar > More > Settings > Backup > Manage backup > Disable desktop sync.

According to "[Back up your Documents, Pictures, and Desktop folders with OneDrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjvLc.png)", you need to move files and folders from OneDrive desktop folder to the desktop folder under user profile folder manually.

[image]

And then you'd better check the desktop folder default location. More information, please refer to "[Windows 10 User Shell Folders Restore Default Paths](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/)". Please make sure the data value for Desktop registry is `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`.

[image]

Please remember to restart your computer to check your issue.

Comment: I stopped one drive from syncing, but it still is using one drive folder.

Comment: You have to move the folder after you stop synchronizing